# how do I prevent git clones from being automatically added to .idea/vcs.xml

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a build tree with a much of synchronously managed git repositories in it.

In the tree there are non exitsant directories that are cloned from third party repositories as part of the build setup process.  These directories are listed in the .gitignore file in the parent directory.

For some reason intellij keeps adding it into the .idea/vcs.xml file which causes problems and I keep having to remove it.  Otherwise it shows up in the "common local branches" area , or prevents "common local branches" from showing up. This causes problems :)

Is there a way to turn off this behavior ?  Is it a bug ?

Comment: It's not a bug, IDE will search for .git folder in folders that are not excluded from a project (please see File | Settings | Editor | File Types -> Ignored files and folders)

Comment: @RuslanKuleshov  well it is a really annoying feature :)  the "project" has parts that are cloned in the build, yet they should not be part of the items in the .idea/vcs.xml  - desired so they show up in the project directory listings, and so they actually build in the project but where they come from is managed by the build scripts.  They are included in all the .gitignore files.